# ASP.NET application to make a skype call

Tags: asp.net, skype

I want to develop a web application that will have textbox and button.  When the user enters a number and clicks on the submit button, I want to make a Skype call from the host.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Er... you're in for a world of pain. First, sure, your server could possibly make a skype call, but how would you handle the back-and-forth to your user's browser? Tons of custom programming with a rich client framework, that's how.

Better to let the user just use skype themselves. Look into the `callto://` URI header for details.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you setup your links with callto:// prefixes? If the user has the option enabled in Skype then the application will be associated with those links.

[How to Use the Skype Callto:// Links](http://www.ehow.com/how_2008799_use-skype-links.html)

Perhaps you could build a link on the fly and initiate a call this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a link with HTML with a **callto:** address to launch the Skype client and make the call (if the client software is configured to do so), which is hopefully what you're looking for. See: http://chrisabraham.com/2005/05/05/how-to-hyperlink-to-a-skype-call-with-your-skype-contact-id-or-telephone-number/

If you want to actually get into the API, you'll need some kind of desktop C# application and interface with the Skype API, see following for details:

http://share.skype.com/sites/devzone/2006/12/c_example_project_for_skype4co.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/skypecontrolapicsharp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

So lets say you did launch a process on the server and automate the skype client on the web server.  It then dials your customer via a phone located in the data center and the customer hears .... what?  IIS isn't very talkative.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but we are getting a few visitors to our site from it. If you want to embed clickable links into your website that work with Skype please use the Skype URIs, see: https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri.

[Skype:echo123?call][1]